# properties file for JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

So my question is related to my previous post: [SQLException : No value specified for parameter 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182880/sqlexception-no-value-specified-for-parameter-1)

I have no idea what a properties file is. Can I create a properties file from text editor, and have the path set in the catalina.properties file in the Tomcat/conf folder? or do I have the following

```
javabase.jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://200.230.71.12:3306/social
javabase.jdbc.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
javabase.jdbc.username = cepein
javabase.jdbc.password = 1234cinco
```

inserted within shared.loader= in the catalina.properties file?

So anyway I did the following:

```
# starting with file:
shared.loader= /home/shaunkoo/NetBeansProjects/dao.properties
```

and load the file in via

```
private static final String PROPERTIES_FILE = "/NetBeansProjects/dao.properties";
private static final Properties PROPERTIES = new Properties();

static {
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream propertiesFile = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(PROPERTIES_FILE);
```

However, I am getting the error that states that /NetBeansProjects/dao.properties is missing in classpath. Any clue what I have done wrong?

Comment: Is there a path/package in your source named `NetBeansProjects/dao.properties`? (If so, that's a weird package name.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *I have no idea what a properties file is.*

A Java `.properties` file is just a configuration file with `key=value` pairs in each line, like a Windows (actually, C++/C#) `.ini` file.

#### See also:

- [Java Tutorials - Essentials - Platform Environment - Properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html)

---

> *Can I create a properties file from text editor, and have the path set in the catalina.properties file in the Tomcat/conf folder?*

It boils down to that the file has to be placed in the Java classpath. In case of a Java web application, you can put it in one of the existing paths which is covered by the classpath, such as `/WEB-INF/classes` (in an IDE, placing the file in root folder of Java source should make it to end up in `/WEB-INF/classes`). You can of course also put it somewhere else and add its root path to the classpath, as you're trying to do with `shared.loader` of Tomcat.

---

> *So anyway I did the following:*
>
> ```
> # starting with file:
> shared.loader= /home/shaunkoo/NetBeansProjects/dao.properties
> ```

This is not correct, it has to point to a folder which represents the classpath root, or to an individual JAR file. In your case, it should be:

```
shared.loader= /home/shaunkoo/NetBeansProjects
```

This way the content of the above folder becomes part of the classpath.

---

> *and load the file in via*
>
> ```
> private static final String PROPERTIES_FILE = "/NetBeansProjects/dao.properties";
> ```

This is not correct, the path for context class loader cannot start with `/` and should not point to a folder which is not **inside** the classpath. You've specified the `/home/shaunkoo/NetBeansProjects` to be part of the classpath, so any files which are inside the folder are accessible by the class loader, not the folder itself. In your case, it should be:

```
private static final String PROPERTIES_FILE = "dao.properties";
```

Answer (score 0):

getResourceAsStream resolves against the classpath, not your filesystem path. So you will need to put the file in your source folder (eg in /src/resources/dao.properties

And then use something like `getResourceAsStream("/resources/dao.properties")`