# Writing to Cloud SQL via Dataflow pipeline is very slow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-sql

I managed to connect to cloud sql via JDBCIO

DataSourceConfiguration.create("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver","jdbc:mysql://google/?cloudSqlInstance=::&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&user=&password=")

This works, however, the batch writes takes between 2-5 minutes for 1000 records, which is terrible. i have tried different networks to see if this was related, and the results were consistent.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: i am curious if it has anything to do with the proxy that dataflow creates to facilitate communication to the instance.....?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you initializing this connection? If you are doing this inside of your DoFn it will create latency as the socket is built up and torn down on each bundle.

Have a look at [DoFn.Setup](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/DoFn.Setup.html) this provides a clean way to init resources that will be persisted across bundle calls.

Comment: thanks for the reply. here is the chunk in question....
p.apply("Reading from file for cloud sql", TextIO.read().from("<ARCHIVE>"))
          .apply("Write to cloud sql", JdbcIO.<String>write().withDataSourceConfiguration(DataSourceConfiguration.create("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver","jdbc:mysql://google/?cloudSqlInstance=::&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&user=&password=")).withStatement("(INSERT STATEMENT) values()")
.withPreparedStatementSetter((element, query) -> {
try
{
// a few setString commands here
}
catch(Exception e)
{
LOG.warn(e.getMessage());
}
})
);

Comment: Are you saying the issue is the above setup?

Comment: Are you using local runner (DirectRunner) or the DataflowRunner? And version of Beam are you using?

Comment: i am using DirectRunner currently, although i have tried both, and same issue.

Comment: version is 2.5.0 of Beam APis

Comment: Hmm - this is odd. Can you re-run the job on the DataflowRunner and post a job id?

Comment: Absolutely. I’ll do it now. Give me about 15 min

Comment: job id = 2018-09-22_07_11_24-12308066841020523793

i'll leave it running, let me know when i can kill it

Comment: according to the job, it took over 3 hours to write 99,000 records, and it is still not done yet (there is around 110,000 records if i recall).....see anything out of the norm?

Comment: update: it ended up being over 5 hours and some change before i killed it.

Comment: Side note, I tried Spanner (just to see if there were similar issues) and had no issues. Spanner wrote 130000 records in around 2-5 seconds.

Comment: I created a request to have someone look at this in more detail. Please ping this thread if you don't see an update in the next few days.

Comment: Two things to investigate: 1) There are ton of There is a lot of "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1"  exceptions in the job logs.  Can you look at your logs and see where this might be surfacing?  2) Can you log the steps in your DoFn.Setup() - can you confirm that you are not doing any custom setup?

Comment: I don't think we have tested the JDBCIO -> Cloud SQL connection properly so there can be performance issues there. I would also check the error Eric mentioned earlier. Currently JDBCIO is configured to push batches of 1K records.

Comment: Probably related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182880/sqlexception-no-value-specified-for-parameter-1.

Comment: Feel free to create a Beam JIRA if you think the issue is in Beam code.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks will test Eric. Even when testing locally, it still take the same amount of time, very slow. I’ll go ahead and file a ticket. Where can I do this?

Comment: Link for creating a JIRA here. You can also try to reach the community through dev list or Slack.

Comment: i need to test this on Beam 2.8 to see if this is any better. I had to move on and make progress in other areas. It doesn't look like i can log issues either via Jira. Communicating via Slack was not very helpful, as it seems rare to get a response.